# Modulo in Cython

Tags: python, cython, modulo

What is the easiest and fastest way to do a modulo operation (`5 % 2`) in Cython code? It seems that using `%` slows down the code a lot, so is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-division, use the compiler directive `cython.cdivision`. Note that there will be different semantics for handling the modulus of negative numbers.

Comment: This means decorate your functions like this `@cython.cdivision(True)`

Comment: @Korem: thanks. (feel free to use suggested edits for dead links)

Answer (score -1):

I use % operator everywhere, and I don't think it slows the code. In fact, % is really fast! Are you declaring your variables with cdef? Maybe you are adding too much python overhead just because of that.

Comment: Ahh I use cdivision by default in my cython headers.

Answer (score -2):

Can you use the builtin `divmod` instead? This function takes two arguments and returns the tuple of their quotient and remainder.

```
>>> 10 % 7
3
>>> divmod(10,7)
(1, 3)
>>> -7 % 3
2
>>> divmod(-7,3)
(-3, 2)
```

Comment: `divmod` is not optimized by Cython, so it will become a Python function call. Those are pretty expensive.

Comment: @Fred I wonder if there is anything divmod is optimized by - if not Cython. to Paul - I agree. Tough crowd, and it would be great if divmod did what the hardware does.